# Testing a procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

I'm new to PL/SQL and I think Ive created a procedure inside of my package body, when i run it in SQL commands it says it been successfully created, I am just not sure how to test it?

The procedure is to delete a customer based on their ID

Here is the code

```
 PROCEDURE remove_customer (customer_id VARCHAR2) IS
 BEGIN
 DELETE FROM customer 
 WHERE customer.customer_id = remove_customer.customer_id;
 END;
```

any idea on how to test it works?

Thanks

Comment: A procedure definition that exists in a package body that is not included in the package is private and can not be accessed outside the package body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would just run it as:

```
begin
  your_package_name.remove_customer('abc');
  -- commit; -- optional if you want to commit it.
end;
/
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that worked fine. Ill mark it as answered when i can

Answer (score 3):

You can run it from an [anonymous block](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/overview.htm#i8859):

```
begin
    your_package.remove_customer('CUST_ID');
end;
/
```

If you're using SQL*Plus or SQL Developer there's a shorthand for this with the [`execute`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve022.htm) command:

```
exec your_package.remove_customer('CUST_ID');
```

And then check that the customer you tried to delete is no longer in the table...

Comment: The last sentence is a critical step too many developers forget in testing.